# overview of billed ressources over all projects of one billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On GCP, I can have several projects, and each project can have several ressources. When it comes to billing, I would like to have an overview of all ressources currently incurring costs that are associated to one billing account, not just associated with one project. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the overall charges for a single billing account through the [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history) section in the cloud console. Check the ["How-to Guides"](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to) section on Cloud Billing for other ways to manage and review your Cloud spending

Comment: Maybe the formulation of my question was not clear enough. I don't want do see charges, I want to see ressources incurring charges. You point to the documentation. I assume that with the provided APIs, it is possible to write a "program" that does what I want, but I am looking for a "built-in" way to do that.

Comment: you can list resources at a project level but not for all projects you own. Not natively at least. You could run a script that pulls a list of all your projects and then lists each resource within each project.